# Compare number dont work properly in C

Tags: c, compare

I'm trying to compare 3 random numbers , but I'm getting that the first number is always the lower, and get the valor of the real lower number, I don't know where I'm failing, here is the code

```
void winner(int team1, int team2, int team3){

if (team1 < team2 && team1 < team3){
    printf("Team 1 winner %d seconds\n", team1);
}
if (team2 < team1 && team2 < team3){
    printf("Team 2 winner %d seconds\n", team2);
}
if (team3 < team1 && team3 < team2){
    printf("Team 3 winner %d seconds\n", team3);
}
if (team1 == team2 && team1 < team3){
    printf("Draw Team 1 and Team 2, %d seconds\n", team1);
}
if (team1 == team3 && team1 < team2){
    printf("Draw Team 1 and Team 3, %d seconds\n", team1);
}
if (team2 == team3 && team2 < team1){
    printf("Draw Team 2 and Team 3, %d seconds\n", team2);
}
if (team1 == team2 && team2 == team3){  //Fixed this compare, tanks Guilles
    printf("Draw Team 1, Team 2 and Team 3, %d seconds\n", team1);
}
}
```

I'm always getting the first "if" as result, or if 2 numbers are equals, I get the 4th "if"

I'm calling the function whit

```
winner(WEXITSTATUS(team1), WEXITSTATUS(team2), WEXITSTATUS(team3));
```

I'm adding the part where I get, team1, team2, and team3

```
int corredores(int equipo){
struct timespec tw = { .tv_sec = 0, .tv_nsec = 10000000 };
pid_t Cp, Rn1, Rn2;
int min = 2, max = 6;
int T1, T2, TC;

Cp = fork();            //Creacion del capitan

if (Cp == -1){
    printf("Un Capitan no esta listo, no habra carrera\n");
    exit(-1);
}

else if (Cp == 0){      //Codigo del Capitan
    nanosleep(&tw, 0);
    Rn2 = fork();       //Creacion del Segundo Corredor

    if (Rn2 == -1){
    printf("El Segundo Corredor de un Equipo no esta listo, no habra carrera\n");
    exit(-1);
    }

    else if (Rn2 == 0){     //Codigo del Segundo corredor
        nanosleep(&tw, 0);
        Rn1 = fork();       //Creacion del Primer corredor
        if (Rn1== -1){
            printf("El Primer Corredor de un Equipo no esta listo, no habra carrera\n");
            exit(-1);
        }

        else if (Rn1 == 0){     //Codigo del Primer corredor
            srand(getpid());
            nanosleep(&tw, 0);
            T1 = aleatorio(min, max);
            printf("El tiempo del Primer Corredor del Equipo %d es de %d segundos\n",equipo, T1);
            sleep(T1);
            exit(T1);
        }
        wait(&T1);
        srand(getpid());
        T2 = aleatorio(min, max);
        printf("El tiempo del Segundo Corredor del Equipo %d es de %d segundos\n",equipo, T2);
        nanosleep(&tw, 0);
        sleep(T2);
        T2 = T2 + WEXITSTATUS(T1);
        exit(T2);
    }
    wait(&T2);
    srand(getpid());
    TC = aleatorio(min, max);
    printf("El tiempo Capitan del Equipo %d es de %d segundos\n",equipo, TC);
    nanosleep(&tw, 0);
    sleep(TC);
    TC = TC + WEXITSTATUS(T2);
    exit(TC);
}

return WEXITSTATUS(TC);
}
```

and called by

```
team1 = corredores(equipo);
```

added, "aleatorio" function, i think it work properly

```
int aleatorio(int min, int max){
return rand() % (max-min+1) + min;
```

}

i think the problem is somewhere here

```
    wait(&team1);
wait(&team2);
wait(&team3);
printf("======================================\n");
ganador(WEXITSTATUS(team1), WEXITSTATUS(team2), WEXITSTATUS(team3));
```

The first function ending gets team1,the second, team2, and the third team3
for example, team1 = 14 s , team2 = 9 s , team 3 = 11 s

after that i get, team1 = 9 s, team2 = 11s, team3 = 14s

Comment: You could reduce this code by half probably... there's a lot of redundancies in here

Comment: @DanielS.: _"Macro: int WEXITSTATUS (int status)
If WIFEXITED is true of status, this macro returns the low-order 8 bits of the exit status value from the child process. "_

Comment: I'm pretty sure if you call your method like follows, you will not get the first if: winner(2, 1, 2);

Comment: Show us your W... macros. The problem is most likely in there.

Comment: @DanielS.: Google the macro, it wasn't written by OP. [see waitpid man](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html) for example... However, I must say: looking at usage + `printf` formats, I think the OP doesn't really understand what they return

Comment: Apart from `(team2 == team3) == team1`, which should to be written `team1 == team2 && team2 == team3` (or some variation), your function does what you want. The problem is in the part of the code you didn't show, the one that computes `team1`, `team2` and `team3`. Post a complete program that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last addition to the post makes it a bit more clear.
You wait for 3 child processes like this:

```
wait(&team1);
wait(&team2);
wait(&team3);
```

So team1..team3 will have the exit code of those processes. But the function `wait` does not wait for any specific process, the first wait will return the exit code of the first child process exiting. So you will never know whether team1 will be the score of team1 or team2 or team3!

Because the child processes sleep depending on the score, the first process which stops will have the lowest score, because processes with a higher score sleep longer. So in your case team1 will always be the team with the lowest score.

Comment: no, team 2 are 3 runners, im adding the time of the first runner (T1), to the time of the second runner (T2) for getting the total time of the team

Comment: ok, clear. That means the problem can also be in the function `aleatorio`. Looks like something you have to debug. Just call `winner(3,2,1)` to verify if the compare function is ok. But remark the comment from Gilles, your last compare is wrong.

Comment: i added to the post the aleatorio function and where i think the problem is, winner(3,2,1) works properly

Comment: Thanks for the additions. I completely rewrote my answer.

Comment: ask or search a separate followup question. That way everybody will see the new question. If you ask something in a comment here, I am the only one who gets a notification. Your original question was `Compare number dont work properly in C`, now you want to ask something like `How do I get the exit code of a specific child process`. This is clearly something else. Others can probably answer that better than I can.